# Update table, add data if doesnt exist

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update table and add data if it doesnt exist in the table row.

```
$data = "red flowers";
$id = "12";

mysql_query("update shares set data = data + '".$data."'  WHERE id = '".$id."' LIMIT 1")
```

But it doesnt work. What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: Is this all the code you are using?

Comment: Can you please give more details? What do you expect to happen when you add the string `red flowers` to the current `data` content?

Comment: Is there any short way to check data if exist and then add the value ?

Comment: Check the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `REPLACE` statement instead of `UPDATE`.
It works exactly the same as a `INSERT` statement, but it will replace the data if data with the same primary keys exists.

Ex:
`mysqli_query("REPLACE INTO shares (id,data) values (".$id.",'".$data."')");`

You should sanitize your data to avoid SQL Injection.
You need `DELETE` privileges for this statement to work

Answer (score 0):

First of all **mysql_query** is deprecated use **mysqli_query** or **PDO**.

Secondly don't use simple sql statements while constructing query. Use prepared statement , thereby preventing your code from mysql injections.

Thirdly, use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html for insert if doesn't exist else update case.